# Understanding GazeProvider GazeDirection Vector3

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens, mrtk

I am working on taking two HoloLens 2 users' gaze data, and comparing them to verify they are tracking the same hologram's trajectory.  I have access to the GazeProvider data, no issues there.  However, the GazeProvider.GazeDirection data throws me.  For instance, I've referenced the API at:

[GazeDirection API Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.mixedreality.toolkit.input.gazeprovider.gazedirection?view=mixed-reality-toolkit-unity-2020-dotnet-2.7.0#Microsoft_MixedReality_Toolkit_Input_GazeProvider_GazeDirection)

But, I dont really understand what the Vector 3 it returns means. Are the X,Y,Z relative motion?  If not, can I use Vector3.angle to compute relative motion vectors between two points?

Comment: As long as not further defined I would always assume a `Vector3` is a direction in Unity World space. `Vector3.Angle` gives you the angle between two vectors but no information whatsoever about the direction of that delta .. it can basically mean any vector on a cone around the original vector .. so this wouldn't be what you want to use. Instead you could rather use actual positions via `headPosition + gazeDirection` and then calculate the path between these points -> trajectory. Then you can normalize and compare these trajectories

Comment: `verify they are tracking the same hologram's trajectory` afaik the GazeProvider anyway tells you what object is being gazed at [`GazeProvider.GazeTarget`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.mixedreality.toolkit.input.gazeprovider.gazetarget?view=mixed-reality-toolkit-unity-2020-dotnet-2.7.0#Microsoft_MixedReality_Toolkit_Input_GazeProvider_GazeTarget) .. couldn't you directly use that information?

Comment: @derHugo - Using the Target was my first idea, but the users gaze slips on and off the GameObject and makes computing trajectory over time difficult. Thank you for the help, though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The vector returned by the GazeDirection property leveraging three coordinate parameters to point the direction that the user's eyes are looking towards. The origin is located between the user's eyes. The Vector3.angle method you mentioned can help you compute the angle between the two eye gaze directions.

Comment: Thank you!  Just so I understand, the GazeDirection point in 3D space is the point along a straight line from between my eyes along the gaze ray?  If so, the difference between two of these points would be the vector that give 3D direction between two GazeDirectons?

Comment: The answer to the first question is yes. , the value should be a unit vector without a scalar to special a direction. On the second question, the Vector3.angle will return a float value as the angle in degrees between two GazeDirectons, for more information please refer to: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Angle.html

Answer (score 0):

I have just started to dig into gaze from a different scenario, but one suggestion I would make is that you also take a look at the [gaze origin api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.mixedreality.toolkit.input.gazeprovider.gazeorigin?view=mixed-reality-toolkit-unity-2020-dotnet-2.7.0).

Each user occupies a different location in space and is gazing into the world  in a "gaze direction" from their location in space which would be their "gaze origin".

Basically you need to reconcile the different spatial coordinate systems.